# The 'typing' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller

Tags: python, module, console, pyinstaller, windows-console

When I try to convert my python file to exe using pyinstaller.

Input:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка (5)> pyinstaller -F  send.py
```

I got this error.

Output:

```
The 'typing' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller. 
Please `pip uninstall typing` then try again.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for everybody who did not helped me. I found solution on my own, I needed to write on console this:

```
pip uninstall typing
```

That's all

Answer (score 1):

U can in the file *compat.py* of pyinstaller line:

```
for name in ["enum34", "typing"]:
```

and remove "typing"

```
for name in ["enum34"]:
```

It seems to work ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).